# Kendo Grid, how to translate column menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, translation

I would like to translate column menu in Kendo Data grid (see image below).

[image]

Im able to translate  messages and operators like this:

```
filterable: {
                mode: "row",
                messages: {
                    info: $translate.instant('SELECT'),
                    and: $translate.instant('AND'),
                    or: $translate.instant('OR')
                },
                operators: { // redefine the string operators
                    string: {
                        contains: $translate.instant('CONTAINS'),
                        doesnotcontain: $translate.instant('NOT_CONTAINS'),
                        startswith: $translate.instant('STARTS_WITH'),
                        endswith: $translate.instant('ENDS_WITH'),
                        eq: $translate.instant('IS_EQUAL_TO'),
                        neq: $translate.instant('NOT_EQUAL_TO')
                    }
                }
            },
```

How can I translate menu items?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGrid has option for column menu messages

```
columnMenu: {
    messages: {
        columns: "Choose columns",
        filter: "Apply filter",
        sortAscending: "Sort (asc)",
        sortDescending: "Sort (desc)"
    }
}
```